# Watir/Ruby : How to click on a text in dropdown in Ruby/Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I am using the WATIR-Ruby for my Web Application. I am currently facing an issue clicking on a   text element that is populated dynamically when a search bar  is partially/completely filled with text. The code is unable to identify the element I am trying to click.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Hmv.png

I am unable to click on any of the results obtained from the search.

Here is the HTML source :

```
<div class="results" style="display: block;">
 <ul>
    <li nodeid="111">Profile_Child</li>
    <li nodeid="222">Profile_Grandchild</li>
    <li nodeid="333">Rest_Child2</li>
    <li nodeid="444">rest_grandchild2</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

How would I code for clicking these elements in Ruby/Watir?

Comment: clicking means what ? This is not a drop down list. Althoug it is a good question +1.

Comment: It is not a dropdown .You will get a clear idea if you look at the image link in my question. There is an empty search bar where we provide our text. Based on the partial/complete text entered in the search bar a result list is displayed with elements that can be clicked. Clicking on the data takes me to another page in the application

Comment: Yes.. I got that point by seeing the image.. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
@browser.div(:class => "results").ul.li(:text => "Profile_Child").click
```

Comment: I am getting the following Error using the above code : undefined local variable or method `nodeid' for #<Object:0x3ed6cf0> (NameError).. Also would it be possible for me to provide the text in my code instead of the nodeid ?

Comment: Yes it is, replace :nodeid with the :text attribute

Comment: I am receiving the following Error :unable to locate element, using {:text=>"Profile_Child", :tag_name=>"li"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)←[0m –

Comment: Oh! I forgot to add the ul part, So it is only looking at the direct children of the div and not able to find the lis.